# What method should be used to read XML data in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer-11

I ran into a problem in my project where the values of XML nodes were returned as `undefined` in IE11 while they were returned as the expected valid values in all other browsers, including Edge.

To get the values I was using `.innerHTML` and after some research, I found out that `.innerHTML` doesn't work in IE11 and that technically it shouldn't be used to read XML node values in the first place.

I found a few solutions that all seemed hacky to me because they suggested using different methods of reading XML data for different browsers (aka IE11 and everything else). I figured there must be a standard way to read XML data that would work in all browsers since parsing XML is extremely common, not an obscure practice that would have different implementations in different browsers.

I finally found one video where a guy explained using `.firstChild.data` to read XML node values. I've implemented that in my project and it seems to work fine across all browsers. That's the only time I've come across this method. Everywhere else I looked suggested using `.text()`, `.innerHTML`, or `.textContent` (for IE11).

Is there a reason why `.firstChild.data` isn't or shouldn't be used and are there other methods that are cross browser compatible that are preferable?

Comment: Show us the code you have problems with

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far and some example data.

Comment: I'm not actually having any problems with the code anymore, as I stated in the body where I wrote "I've implemented that in my project and it seems to work fine across all browsers."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) is a [`text node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType), then you want to use [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) to access its text content. See also the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property.

However, the `firstChild` may NOT be a text node, depending on your data. For example, given this XML document…

```
<root><a><b>foo</b> bar</a></root>
```

…the `firstChild` of the `<a>` element is an `Element` with text node child. So you would not want to use `firstChild` to find the text node.

Further, `data` is specific to [`CharacterData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData) interface. If you're sure you have a `Text` node, then you can use this property. Otherwise, I'd personally use the interfaces on `Node` itself until you know what type of node you have.